# maven verify (sonar) fail to resolve defined argument

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am trying to verify using this parameter (which work for other projects)

```
mvn -X verify sonar:sonar -Drevision=4.0.10
```

Maven fails to download dependency because of the argument not resolved

> Failed to execute goal on project APP-ear: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.orginternational:APP-ear:ear:4.0.10:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.orginternational:APP-was:war:4.0.10: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for com.orginternational:APP-was:war:4.0.10: Could not
>   transfer artifact com.orginternational:APP:pom:${revision} from/to en
>   (https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-central/): Failed to
>   transfer file
>   https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-central/com/orginternational/APP/$%7Brevision%7D/APP-$%7Brevision%7D.pom
>   with status code 400 -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal on project APP-ear: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project com.orginternational:APP-ear:ear:4.0.10: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at com.orginternational:APP-was:war:4.0.10

Any clue how to fix this please?

Comment: Do you have flatten-maven-plugin in your build? Cause it looks like you are using ci friendly...BTW: For running sonar you have to do `mvn install sonar:sonar ..`

Comment: no flatten-maven-plugin  and regarding maven it is run after a first maven install goal so it is correct like it , here my issue is really that at some point it did not replace the argument

Comment: First it is **NOT** correct cause if you don't use flatten plugin your configuration is simply wrong. [Explicitly mentioned in the docs ](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). It would also very helpful to have an example project where I can take a look at ...

Comment: thanks khmarbaise  you are right ! that made me notice  another config issue in this project that i need to fix to make it work